# Using SQL Where to perform AND OR then AND comparison of results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, comparison

I need to perform a search that first looks for two variables (using an or), and then I need to compare against those using and.

So here's what I'm essentially trying to accomplish in order:

```
SELECT STUFF
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE Variable1 = 'value' 
    OR Variable2 = 'value2'
    AND Variable3 like '%value3%'
GO
```

I'm essentially trying to do the **or** first, and then from the results of the **or** statement, I need to only add the results that match the variable3 **like** comparison. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at 'Operator Precedence': http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html `AND` takes precedence over `OR`, so you have to use brackets (which take precedence over `AND`)

Comment: Depending on what your actual query looks like, you need to also be aware that the system *doesn't* evaluate the predicates in a strict, left-to-right (or any other defined) order - it will evaluate them in any order it finds convenient to do so. This can catch people out if later predicates depend on e.g. type conversions that earlier predicates should "prevent" from occurring if the data types aren't appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy.

```
SELECT STUFF
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE (Variable1 = 'value' OR Variable2 = 'value2')
    AND Variable3 like '%value3%'
```

Remember, brackets take precedence.